# Convert Shapefiles into Raster -- C++

Tags: qgis, raster, shapefile, convert, c++

I'm coding an algorithm which uses as an input a map from QGIS. The software has been implemented in C++ and my idea is to convert, automatically, a shapefile into a raster one.

Is there any function in C++, from the QGIS api, to perform this task automatically? Besides: is there any data structure in the QGIS framework to handle matrices which comes from raster files?

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to locate an API method in QGIS to do it, but there is a GDAL function: [GDALRasterizeGeometries](http://www.gdal.org/gdal__alg_8h.html#a50caf4bc34703f0bcf515ecbe5061a0a) (there are a couple of variants.) This method is used internally by [gdal_rasterize](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html).